# Avalanche - How do I get networkId?? (No ChainId)

Tags: web3js, blockchain, eip, networkid, avax

I am trying to get networkID with web3 in avalanche testnet, according to avalanche documentation:

> On Mainnet, the C-Chain uses 1 and 43114 for these values. On the Fuji Testnet, it uses 1 and 43113 for these values. networkID and chainID can also be obtained using the net_version and eth_chainId methods.

https://docs.avax.network/build/avalanchego-apis/c-chain

But if run the following code I get 43113 for both networkId and chainId

```
const web3 = new Web3('https://api.avax-test.network/ext/bc/C/rpc');
console.log(await web3.eth.net.getId(), await web3.eth.getChainId());
```

How am I supposed to get both values correctly (1 and 43113)?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried making an RPC request directly?

Comment: @0xCourtney yes with ethers, response same values (43113, 43113)

Comment: Yea, that's clearly not right. I recommend asking in Avalanche's discord about this.